# css - dynamic div height

Tags: html, css, frontend

problem shown: http://test.aussieclubroom.com/test.html

I have a div in which content is dynamically generated into. On the left of the example URL, is the current div I have. notice the container div's height is fixed (mainContent_mid_right), and so are the left and right border divs (mainContent_mid_right_left and mainContent_mid_right_right).

However, I would like the div to be dynamic in height, so I set the parent div (mainContent_mid_right) to height:auto, and the left and right border divs to height:auto. this is the div on the right of the URL given. However, as you can see, the border divs are not appearing, can anyone help me fix this?

thanks,
daniel

Comment: Your code is a little bit of a mess. If you remove all inline styles in your containers and in the table it sort of works. I just removed those with devtools and it looks much better. Plus, if you're using `!important` that many times something must be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the rounded-corners effect you are trying to achieve with all these divs, is actually the border-radius CSS property. Should help you clear all this mess!

Comment: Indeed. [Here is an example using a single div and border-radius](http://jsfiddle.net/gothick/YPAjU/3/) (and an inset box-shadow, to match the desired look as closely as possible.) Looks pretty nice in webkit and Firefox, and will degrade gracefully in less able browsers to a simple box.

Comment: @MattGibson thanks for doing that. does jsfiddle support the ability to view the html on other browsers (i.e. older firefox/ie browsers)?

Comment: @dgamma3 No, for that you'd need a browser testing service like, say, [browserling](http://browserling.com/), [BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#), or something like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) (which I use within a virtual machine.) Tip: target the highest version of IE you can get away with. If you can ignore IE6 (perhaps because that's only 0.5% of your visitors), you'll save yourself a lot of development time. And frustration.